# What are the semantics of not using "FTWL to guarantee that the dump file is consistent with metadata"?

Tags: mysql, tidb, mydumper

When migrating data from AWS RDS MySQL to TiDB using [DM](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/dm-overview) we got the following error:

```
Couldn't acquire global lock, snapshots will not be consistent: Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

The TiDB [documentation](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb-data-migration/v1.0/migrate-from-mysql-aurora#step-6-query-the-task) suggested the following configuration change for DM.

```
mydumpers:
  global:
    extra-args: "--no-locks"
```

However, the same doc mentioned the following:

> If it is acceptable to not use FTWL to guarantee that the dump file is
> consistent with metadata or the upstream can pause writing data, you
> can skip the above error by adding the --no-locks argument for
> extra-args under mydumpers.

What are the practical implications of **not using FTWL to guarantee that is the dump file is consistent with metadata**?

For example, will this result in data loss? Or data corruption? Or slightly outdated database metrics?

Answer (score 0):

The product doc referenced for the --no-locks argument is from v1.0 and not recommended.
You may find the latest version of the [documentation for migrating from Aurora to TiDB](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb-data-migration/v5.3/migrate-from-mysql-aurora) helpful.